# createEnvelope with CompositeTemplate error

Tags: php, sdk, docusignapi

Modifying the sample code for embedded signing to use a CompositeTemplate resulted in the following error.

msg: Access to undeclared static property: stdClass::$swaggerTypes
file: $home/lib/docusign/src/ObjectSerializer.php
line: 68

This happens on the attempt to serialize SignHere:scale_value, which is an object, but a standard object, not a Swagger object, and the serializer assumes ALL objects are Swagger objects. Not sure if the SDK is mistakenly assuming scale_value is an object (seems it should just be a scalar) or there's a missing ScaleValue model class.

Anyone run into this before?

Comment: Indeed appears to be a bug in the SDK. Awaiting confirmation before submitting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this was definitely a bug in the SDk. Bug reported but no idea how long it will take to be fixed.
If you run into this issue, just open src/Model/SignHere.php and change the type of scale_value to string instead of object.